# Usage of typename in typedef versus inheritance

Tags: c++, syntax, typename

Just wondering about C++ `typename`, used to tell the parser that some symbols are types. Why must we use it after `typedef` and not for inheritance?

Example: imagine you have this

```
struct C { /* a class */ }; 
template<class T> struct S {
   typedef C type; // S<T>::type is a type
};
```

What's bothering me is this:

```
template<class T> struct Typedef {
   typedef typename S<T>::type MyType; // needs typename
};
template<class T> struct Inheritance
   :  S<T>::type                       // doesn't need typename
{ };
```

In both cases the parser should expect a type, so it could parse `S<T>::type` as one. Why does it only do so for inheritance, and not for typedefs? The pattern seems the same to me:

```
typedef $type$ $new_symbol$;
class $new_symbol$ : $type$ { $definition$ };
```

Or is there a usage of `typedef` I'm not aware of, which make this ambiguous?

PS: I'm pretty sure this has already been asked, but I can't find it (there's a lot of noise related to the `typename` keyword). This question is only about the syntax, not whether it's better to use inheritance or typedefs. I appologize in advance if there's a duplicate.

Comment: It has been answered before. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: @PetrBudnik The link doesn’t actually contain an answer to this specific question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It certainly does and in great detail. Read the accepted answer's sections **The "typename" keyword** and **Additional notes and examples**.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: I just read both sections, the answer is detailed as you said, but I couldn't find an answer there :\

Comment: @Petr You’re mistaken. Read my answer here, and tell me where this information is explained in the accepted answer of the other question. Johannes doesn’t even mention `typedef` (and the one code snippet which uses a `typedef` doesn’t have a dependent name, and consequently doesn’t require a `typename`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I stand corrected. Indeed, while it is shown that `typename` is needed in case of `typedef` and is not allowed in base-class list, it does not explain the reasons behind it for `typedef` case as explained in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `typedef` syntax is more variable than the inheritance syntax. *Normally* you would write `typedef` *first*, and the type name *second*. But the order is actually unimportant. To wit, the following is a valid `typedef`:

```
int typedef integer_type;
```

Now consider what happens if we use a dependent name:

```
S<T>::type typedef integer_type;
```

Without doing some non-trivial lookahead, the parser cannot know that `S<T>::type` refers to a type name here (because it hasn’t yet seen the `typedef`), so by the disambiguation rules it infers a value. For consistency in the grammar, there is no special case for prefixed `typedef` (which, you are right, *is* unambiguous). There could be a special case, but there simply isn’t.

Comment: Thanks for this short and to the point anser! I didn't know this syntax, this was exactly what I was looking for;)